# Why is 'this' treated differently when used with function objects?

Tags: javascript, properties, this

In trying to understand the 'this' keyword in JavaScript, I've looked at many resources, including the answers on this popular Stack Overflow question:
[How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

I don't know if I am misunderstanding something, but everything I've read seems to be incomplete and missing a rule:
Even though functions are objects, 'this' is treated differently for function-objects vs. other objects.

Consider the following code:

```
var object = {};
object.name = "object";
object.logMyName = function() { 
  console.log(this.name);
};
object.logMyName();
```

Because a function ('logMyName') is called on an object ('object'), 'this' is set to the object ('object') upon which the function ('logMyName') was called.

Now consider the following code:

```
var funcObject = function() {};
funcObject.name = "funcObject";
funcObject.logMyName = function() { 
  console.log(this.name);
};
funcObject.logMyName();
```

Although a function ('logMyName') was called on an object ('funcObject'), 'this' is **not** set to the object ('funcObject') upon which the function ('logMyName') was called.

Why does this discrepancy between types of objects exist, and why is it rarely/never discussed?

Comment: The 2nd code example uses an anonymous function. When I drop that code into jsfiddle, then "this.name" returns blank. The name property appears to be read-only & can't be set with `funcObject.name = "funcObject";`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because functions have a special [`name`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-instances-name) property.

> The value of the `name` property is an String that is descriptive of the
>   function. The name has no semantic significance but is typically a
>   variable or property name that is used to refer to the function at its
>   point of definition in ECMAScript code. This property has the
>   attributes { [[Writable]]: **false**, [[Enumerable]]: **false**,
>   [[Configurable]]: **true** }.

That property is not writable, so your assignment is ignored.

However, since it's configurable, you can redefine it:

```
var funcObject = function() {};
Object.defineProperty(funcObject, 'name', {
  configurable: true,
  value: "funcObject"
});
funcObject.logMyName = function() { 
  console.log(this.name);
};
funcObject.logMyName(); // logs "funcObject"
```

Note some old browsers implemented it as non-configurable before ES6 standardized it as configurable, so the code above might not work.

Comment: You're right.  I thought that this was a symptom of 'this' behavior, but it appears that it was simply due to read-only properties.  I was not aware that JavaScript had such a thing as read-only properties.  Which unfortunately fail silently.